# How to execute a python code from coffee script and get the output

Tags: python, node.js, coffeescript

I am developing a CoffeeScript which needs to execute a Python program and get the responses from the Python code.
My coffee script is

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.respond /greetme/i, (msg) ->
        sender = msg.message.user.name.toLowerCase()
        @exec = require('child_process').exec
        command = "python3 ext-scripts/hello.py"
        @exec command, (out1) ->
            msg.send out1
        msg.send "Hello " + sender
        msg.finish()
```

and my python code is hello.py

```
print("hey indhu")
return "reached the python file"
```

I need to get the output "reached the python file" to 6th line in coffee script. to send out the message

I am getting error while doing this exec out function.

> message: Error: Command failed: python3 ext-scripts/hello.py   File "ext-scripts/hello.py", line 28
> return "reached the python file"
> ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
>
> error: Response not OK:  no_text

How to make it work? I am a Python developer and new to CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with a supprecess that reads the output and filters. The first version is good for Windows machines, the second for Linux systems.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'More output'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
stdout, stderr
```

OR

```
import os

cmd = 'your command here'
terminal_output = os.system(cmd)

print(terminal_output)
```

Comment: what about Mac os?

Comment: Mac os is based on the Bash shell like Linux. You can use the Linux version.

Comment: sorry to ask again. I would like to run a python code though coffeescript and i need to receive the responses of the py code at the @exec line with out1 in coffee script. So my question is how to send a response from the python code to catch with the given coffee script.. Here the coffee script stays the same i guess/....My understanding is you have given a code to run something from the python file. but my requirement is run a python file from coffeescript. please help

Comment: take the exec example from here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback
which looks like: @exec command, (error, stdout, stderr) -> here you have now access to stdout and the rest